# Permalink redirection.

Tags: permalinks

I have my site hosted by GoDaddy and originally using HTML files. I wanted to move from hard coded to a plugin service, so I installed WordPress. But I'm having an issue redirecting the original homepage (mywpsite.com) within the WordPress dashboard. Is there an easy way to set a new created page to link to mywpsite.com? Do I need any additional plugins? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Can you please clarify your question with an example please?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So the site was originally created a couple of years ago written in HTML and hosted by GoDaddy. I installed the WordPress plugin from the GoDaddy site. So at current, mywpsite.com, directs to a bland page. I want mywpsite.com to direct to a page of my choosing. Would that be possible?

Comment: contact Godaddy support they'll do that, or tell you what you should do.